# Why does fread always return 0?

Tags: c, file-io

I used this code to read file. But fread function always return 0. What is my mistake?

```
FILE *file = fopen(pathToSourceFile, "rb");
if(file!=NULL) 
{
    char aByte[50000];
    int ret = fread(aByte, sizeof(aByte), 1, file);
    if(ret != 0)
    {
        not jump into there;
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(aByte, ret, 1, file);
    }
} 
fclose(file);
```

Comment: Does the file definitely have at least 50000 bytes?

Comment: @Charles, it shouldn't need to.  `fread` should return the number of bytes actually read, which may be less than 50000.

Comment: the file exist so fread must be return not 0 :(.

Comment: @user418304 why did you roll-back to the un-formatted version?

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: No. `fread` returns the number of _objects_ read. If you are reading up to one 50000 byte objects it will return 0 or 1.

Comment: Why was this tagged `C++`. It's pure C.

Comment: The file is larger than 50000 byte because it is standard mp3 file.

Comment: @Charles, you're right; my mistake.  I should have read more carefully.

Comment: Can everyone please _stop_ removing the C++ tag from this question. It is obviously the language that that user418304 _wants_ to use. Just because the code is also valid C doesn't mean that the question is about C. (People don't retag C questions as C++ just because the code uses the common subset, do they?)

Comment: It both compiles and reads properly as C or C++. It is the `fwrite` that is broken.

Comment: its intent was not to shame, it was to be accurate; it was incorrect as written. StackOverflow is searched by many to find answers. I am trying to aid the OP and SO at the same time. If you disagree, please roll-back my change or edit it to suit, I won't "edit war" you.

Comment: @msw Please don't try to justify making fun of the OP with wanting to help them or SO. This kind of behaviour is neither funny nor helping anybody.

Comment: @balpha - don't presume to know my intent, it is unseemly in a moderator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

are you sure that your file has a size greater than 50000 ? otherwise you could try:

```
 fread(aByte,1, sizeof(aByte),  file);
```

Comment: YES because i readed data from a mp3 file that the size on disk is 3.2mb :S

Answer (score 3):

[`ferror()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ferror/) will tell when something is wrong.

You can print the actual error message using [`perror()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/perror/).

Comment: `ferror()` won't tell you *what* is wrong, it'll tell you *if* something is wrong - it's just a true/false indication.  Using `perror()` if `ferror()` returns true is good advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `fwrite` to a file open in `rb` mode.

Your statement that `ret` is always zero is false. If you had properly instrumented your code, you'd not be making false claims:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("junk.dat", "rb");
    if(file!=NULL)
    {
        char aByte[50000];
        int ret = fread(aByte, sizeof(aByte), 1, file);
        fprintf(stderr, "fread returned %d\n", ret);

        if(ret != 0)
        {
            int fs = fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
            if(fs == -1) {
                perror("fseek");
                exit(1);
            }
            fs = fwrite(aByte, ret, 1, file);
            if(fs != ret) {
                perror("fwrite");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Yields:

```
fread returned 1
fwrite: Bad file descriptor
```

when run.

Comment: Yes sorry i change to rb to test fread. please skip to fwrite. :)

Comment: It is best to cut and paste the code that you are actually having problems with end you can edit your question if your code changes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to read a file of size 6553600 bytes (an mp3), and it was returning 0 bytes read. It drove me crazy, till, I tried to manually hardcode 30 bytes, and it did read 30 bytes.

I started playing with it and see how much can it read, and it turns out that it can read exactly 262144 (2^18) bytes, if you ask it to read 262145 bytes it reads 0.

Conclusion: at least with this function you can't load the whole file in one go.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this. I just ran into a similar issue. It is because the 2nd argument to fread should be the size of **each element in the buffer**. In OP's code it is the size of the pointer to the buffer.

This should work provided buff has at least 1 element:

```
int ret = fread(aByte, sizeof(aByte[0]), 1, file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check man fread

[man fread(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html)

```
size_t fread(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *restrict stream);
```

RETURN VALUE

On success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read
or written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred
**only when size is 1**.  If an error occurs, or the end of the file
is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).

As your file is smaller than 50000Bytes aka. size of a item, the read item count is 0.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

```
    fseek(rFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    iTotalSize = ftell(rFile);
    fseek(rFile, 0, SEEK_SET);   // <-- I wrote SEEK_END, not SEEK_SET
```

so it read 0 byte(anything)

Answer (score -1):

Did you:

`#include <unistd.h>`

If not, and if you compile without -Wall, the C compiler can incorrectly assume that the second argument to fread() is an int rather than an off_t, which can mess up the function call. Your code snippet doesn't show any #include statements, so please make sure you're including everything that you're using.